Baby Rudin: Corollary to Theorem 2.12 (at most countable union of at most countable sets is countable)
I am trying to prove the corollary to Theorem 2.12 in Rudin's book. Theorem 2.12 says:

Let $\{E_n\}$, $n = 1,2,3, \ldots$ be a sequence of countable sets, and put $S = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. Then $S$ is countable.

The corollary to this theorem, which Rudin leaves unproved, is:

Suppose $A$ is at most countable, and, for every $\alpha \in A$, $B_{\alpha}$ is at most countable. Put $T = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} B_{\alpha}$. Then $T$ is at most countable.

Rudin suggests that the goal is to exhibit $T$ as a subset of "$S$," which is unspecified but I assume is a countable union of a countable sets into which $T$ injects. A finite subset is certainly at most countable, and an infinite subset of a countable set is countable by Theorem 2.8. I can prove this result with a different strategy. I would first prove that $B_{\alpha}$ is at most countable if and only if there exists a surjection $f_{\alpha}: \mathbb{N}_{+} \to B_{\alpha}$, and then show that there exists a surjection $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to T$ defined by $(i,j) \mapsto f_i (j)$. If there are only finitely many sets, this becomes tricky, but I think I can "append" some distinct sets and create an infinite subset of a countable set.
Regardless, I am not sure what Rudin had in mind or how this follows immediately from Theorem 2.12. I don't think I can say, "keep adding elements to each $B_{\alpha}$ until it's countable." But I could probably use the definition of a finite set to say each $B_{\alpha}$ is equivalent to $J_n = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n$, repeat for each $B_{\alpha}$, and then union with the entire set of positive integers. The union is then just $\mathbb{N}_{+}$, so I'll end up with a subset of a countable set. This set is then equivalent to $T$.
Will either of these strategies work? I am especially interested in discerning what Rudin may have had in mind for this corollary. The result seems a bit more involved to me, but this could be a case of Rudin, as he does, leaving the details to the reader.

Here is my attempt at a proof.

Define $J_n$ as follows: if $n = 0$, $J_0 = \emptyset$; if $n \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$, $J_n = \{1, \ldots, n\}$; if $n = +\infty$, then $J_n = \mathbb{N}_{+}$. As each $B_{\alpha}$ is countable, they are equivalent to $J_n$ for some $n$. Define $\phi: A \to \{B_{\alpha}\}$ sending $\alpha$ to $0$ if $B_{\alpha}$ is empty, $n$ if $B_{\alpha}$ is equivalent to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n$, and $+\infty$ if $B_{\alpha}$ is infinite. Then $|B_{\alpha}| = |J_{\phi(\alpha)}|$, so
$$
\left \lvert \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} B_{\alpha} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} J_{\phi(\alpha)} \right \rvert. 
$$
Each $J_{\phi(\alpha)}$ is by definition a subset of $\mathbb{N}_{+}$. So $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} J_{\phi(\alpha)}$ is a subset of a countable set and therefore at most countable. So $T = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} B_{\alpha}$ is equivalent to a subset of $\mathbb{N}_{+}$ and therefore at most countable.

How does this attempt look? My biggest doubt is where I say that $B_{\alpha} \sim J_{\phi(\alpha)}$ and then assert that the cardinality is "preserved" under taking a possibly infinite union of such sets. I think there may be some circularity in my argument.

I would appreciate if someone could explain the downvote so I can edit the question. I've been working on this more and am going to add my attempt at a proof, though it isn't of the mold I think Rudin was expecting.


This seems more a typo than a serious mistake: Should the codomain of $\phi$ be actually $\mathbb{N}{\ge 0}\cup{+\infty}$ rather than ${B{\alpha}}{\alpha\in A}$? 2. $\left \lvert \bigcup\limits{\alpha \in A} B_{\alpha} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A} J_{\phi(\alpha)} \right \rvert$ is incorrect. Say $A={1,2}$. $B_1={1}$, $B_2={2}$. Then $|B_1\cup B_2|=2$ and $J_{\phi(1)}=J_{\phi(2)}={1}$. Have you found where the problem lies?


If you know the definition of disjoint union, then the following may be more natural to you: 1. There is a surjection ${(x_{\alpha},\alpha): \alpha\in A, x_{\alpha}\in B_{\alpha} }\to \cup_{\alpha\in A} B_{\alpha}$ assigning $x_{\alpha}$ to $(x_{\alpha},\alpha)$. 2. Thus it suffices to argue ${(x_{\alpha},\alpha): \alpha\in A, x_{\alpha}\in B_{\alpha} }$ is at most countable. Can you give an injection from this set to $\mathbb{N}_+^2$? (A casework disscussing if $A$ is infinite may make this easier.)

"I am not sure what Rudin had in mind or how this follows immediately from Theorem 2.12. I don't think I can say, "keep adding elements to each $B_α$
until it's countable."": Yes you can (and same with $A$), and this is for sure what Rudin had in mind.
